# problem with Jquery multiselect2side

Tags: jquery, select

I am using a multiselect2side select.What i need is when the user selects the list items and hits a manual button "create" it should remove all the selected items from the list.
I can remove if the list has only one item, however i am having issues when there are multiple items in the list selected.Below is the code.Any inputs will be appreciated.Below is the code
Thanks

```
    $().ready(function() {
        $('#searchable').multiselect2side({
            search: "Search: "
        })});



    $(document).ready(function() {
        selectCount = document.getElementById('id').value; 
        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {

        var multipleValues = $('#searchable').val() || [];
         //creating a dynamic text box and adding the items selected    
        $('#divTxt').
        append("<li><input id='selectedEle"+(selectCount)+"' name='email"+(selectCount)+"' class='userEmail' size='50'>&nbsp;");

        var temp= 'email'+ selectCount;

        $("#"+temp).val(multipleValues.join(", "));

        selectCount++;

var selectedIpList = $('#searchable').val();
```

var eachItem = [];
    //$("#searchablems2side_*dx option[value='1']").remove();
    $('#searchablems2side*_dx :selected').each(function(i, selected){

```
eachItem[i] = $(selected).val();

$("#searchablems2side__dx option[value=eachItem[i]]").remove();
});
    });
     });
</script>

        </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have not understood question altogether but will give an answer first of all you have got your first `document.ready` **wrong**

instead of like this

```
$().ready(function() {
    $('#searchable').multiselect2side({
        search: "Search: "
    })});
```

it should be like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
});
```

or you can use the `short hand` method

```
$(function(){

});
```

now as i have understood your question you want to `unselect` the check `options` in your `multiselect` on a button `click` by assuming `#searchable` is the `id` of your multiselect

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#btnAdd').click(function() {

        $(#searchable option:selected).each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.removeAttr("selected");    
        });
      });
)};
```

have a look at [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/)  [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)  [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)